# How do I echo out table <tr> horizontally instead of vertically with while-loop?

Tags: php, html

My code echoing the table vertically and thats not what I want.
I have been trying to get it to work the way I want it to but I find it very hard to find a solution becasue of the while loop forcing the table to be vertically.

```
<table style="width:100%">
<?php 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

              echo "<tr><td>$row['user'] </td></tr>";
             }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: `tr` is `row`.. It should be vertical..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment says, a `<tr>` is a Table Row, which means it will create a new row vertically when displayed. The code below puts everything in one row, which will display it horizontally.

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<?php 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

              echo "<td>$row['user'] </td>";
             }
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Subin Thomas stated in the comment, `tr` is used for rows, so basically, they will be vertical. The `td`s inside the row will be horizontal. So, to achieve what you want, you may use this code:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <?php 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<td>$row['user'] </td>";
            }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What we did, is move the `tr` out of the loop, and loop only the `td`s.